# Linux FreeTTS hangs on voice.speak

Tags: linux, freeze, freetts

I have been trying to use FreeTTS in my program but can't seem to actually get it to speak.  All initialization will work with no errors but the program freezes on voice.speak.  I am developing on kali but plan to actually use the program on my pi zero.  Any help would be appreciate.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Speech {

public static String name = "kevin16";
private static Voice voice;
private static VoiceManager vm = VoiceManager.getInstance();

public static void init() {
    voice = vm.getVoice(name);
    voice.allocate();
    voice.speak("This is a test")
}
```

}

Update:
I could not seem to get freetts to work but so far call espeak from java seems to work as an alternative.

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you could share the the code you already have that's not working, so we can figure out what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added my code.